# json passing multiple strings

Tags: asp.net, json

```
    <input id="SubmitCommentsToInvoice" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowCommentBox()" />    
    <script>
                function ShowCommentBox() {
                    var obj =          
                    {
                    "name":"Jim",
                    "Description":"Keep er lit",
                    "Price":"12.5"
                    };

                    $("#WhereNameGoes").text(obj.name);

                    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true });             }
        </script>
<div id="dialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">
         <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
             <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Owed</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td id="WhereNameGoes"></td>
                 <td id="Description"></td>
                 <td id="Price"></td>
             </tr>
         </table> 
         <br />
        </div>
```

Tyring to use JSON n my asp.net project to pass strings and display on screen.
When comment btn is clicked only 'jim' appears in the div...why does description and price not?

Thaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not telling it to. All you've got is:

```
 $("#WhereNameGoes").text(obj.name);
```

You need to set the other two the same way.